# How can I get specific values of a CSV and add them to a JSON with csvparser

Tags: node.js, csv, express

I'm mostly new to nodejs and am making a site that goes through csv data and complies into a table. I am using covid data and the csv file I have has tons of different countries and US states, but I only want the US states. My code right now goes through every row and prints it out in a json format.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
    // [
    //   { 'Province/State': 'North Carolina',
    //     'Country/Region': 'US',
    //     'Last Update': '2020-03-19T23:43:04',
    //      Confirmed: '123',
    //      Deaths: '0',
    //      Recovered: '0',
    //      Latitude: '35.6301',
    //      Longitude: '-79.8064' },
    //      ..... <and so on for every country and every US state.>
    // ]
  });
```

The US states are not in a specific order or specific rows so I need to filter them out by looking at the country region. **However**, the  data is only in single quotes and I get errros when I do a JSON.parse `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`. What is the best way to go through the csv file and be able to parse into json, and parse out only the US states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter US data by checking the `Country/Region` field in the `data` event handler:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => {
    if (data['Country/Region'] === 'US') {
      results.push(data);
    }
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
  });
```